# Como faço para manter as imagens do arquivo word no python docx?

Tags: python, microsoft-word

```
documento = Document(Docx.value)

for paragrafo in documento.paragraphs:
    for codigoN in codigodicionario:
        paragrafo.text = paragrafo.text.replace(
            codigoN, codigodicionario[codigoN])

documento.save('Test.docx')
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.